# Assign value to checkbox

Tags: laravel, checkbox, laravel-5

I have a table row like so

```
<tr class='template4'>
    <td>
        <textarea name='amendsInput[0][addInfo]' id="additionalInput"  placeholder='Additional Information' class="form-control noresize"></textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name='amendsInput[0][deliveryDate]' placeholder='Deployment Date' class="form-control amendsDate"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="col-md-12 checkbox checkbox-danger">
            <input type="checkbox" value='1' name="amendsInput[0][complete]"  class="styled">
            <label for="checkbox">
                Complete
            </label>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I allow the user to add additional table rows.  When they do, the name for each td increases by 1.

In the above, one of my tds is a checkbox.  I essentially want to get a true or false for each table row.  In my controller I am currently doing

```
$campaignAmendsInput = Input::get('amendsInput');
dd($campaignAmendsInput);
```

If I have two table rows, and only check the checkbox in one of these rows, the output is this

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "addInfo" => "Checkbox Checked"
    "deliveryDate" => "03-05-2016"
    "complete" => ""
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "addInfo" => "Checkbox not checked"
    "deliveryDate" => ""
  ]
]
```

So where it was checked, complete is set to an empty string, not 1.  Additionally, where it was not checked, there is no complete element whatsoever (I really want complete to be set to 0).

How can I get the checkbox passing 1 or 0 whether it is checked or not?

Thanks

Comment: What's an example value for amendsInput[0][complete]? Generally Checkboxes don't send a value in form if unchecked

Comment: I added the values in the op.  Really it should be true/false but if checked, it just sends an empty string

Comment: you're probably better off removing the value attribute all together

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
<tr class='template4'>
    <td>
        <textarea name='{{ amendsInput[0][addInfo] }}' id="additionalInput"  placeholder='Additional Information' class="form-control noresize"></textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name='{{ amendsInput[0][deliveryDate] }}' placeholder='Deployment Date' class="form-control amendsDate"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="col-md-12 checkbox checkbox-danger">
            <input type="checkbox" value='1' name="{{ amendsInput[0][complete] }} "  class="styled">
            <label for="checkbox">
                Complete
            </label>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```